# A child has been saying a sentence many times for 5 minutes, then now you answer: "I didn't get it", "I don't get it", or "I haven't got it"?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

A child has been saying a sentence many times for 5 minutes,

then now what would you answered:

"**I didn't get it**",

"**I don't get it**",

or "**I haven't got it**"?

I think "**I haven't got it**" is the best option because you have not understood since he started saying that sentence.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you didn’t understand what the child was saying?

Comment: I want to know what is the best response, because I didn't understand 5 minutes ago & now I still don't understand. So the process has lasted since 5 minutes ago

Comment: "I still can't tell what you're saying."